# UIButton and UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uibezierpath

So I am using **PaintCode** to make shapes, and I want my `UIButton` to have that shape.

The shape I made looks like this in code:

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 81.5, y: 48.5))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 105.5, y: 24.5))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 129.5, y: 48.5))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 123.5, y: 48.5))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 105.5, y: 30.5))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 87.5, y: 48.5))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 81.5, y: 48.5))
bezierPath.closePath()
UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
bezierPath.fill()
UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
bezierPath.lineWidth = 1
bezierPath.stroke()
```

And I set the `UIButton` layers in my `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, but how can I make the shape I made on my button?

Comment: So you basically want that button to have that shape right?

Comment: @KrishWadhwana Yes, correct.

Comment: Have you created a separate class of type UIButton and entered the code in there? Also, have you called the drawRect function?

Comment: @KrishWadhwana What do you mean exactly? A new class for the UIButton?

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want to do, you have to create a new CocoaTouchClass which is a subclass of UIButton by right clicking and choosing "New File". Once you're in that file, you have to override a function called drawRect. This is what your file should look like-

```
import UIKit

class BezierButtonDrawing: UIButton {

    override func drawRect (rect: CGRect) {

      //your code from PaintCode goes here

      }

}
```

All you have to do after that is, go to Main.storyboard, click on your button, and set it's class from the Identity Inspector to "BezierButtonDrawing" or whatever you have named your class.

If you have multiple shapes in your app, you can simply do what RichardG suggested. Here is the swift translation-

declare this in your class first (not in viewDidLoad)

```
var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
```

Next, this is what you do in `viewDidLoad`-

```
self.shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0
self.shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
self.shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath
self.shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
self.yourButton.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

That's it. Just build and run, and you'll have what you wanted :)

Comment: Ok, now what if I have 4 different shapes I want to add to 4 different buttons? Do I then need 4 different classes?

Comment: Simply create four classes for those four buttons, and assign their respective classes to them. It's the easiest way. Also, if you have created some shape, say a hexagon, and you create a class for it, you can assign the same class to multiple buttons also, and those buttons will show up as hexagons.

Comment: I did as you said, but the button does not show any shape? How come?

Comment: Did you go to the Identity Inspector as set the class  BezierButtonDrawing?

Comment: Yes, I set the correct class, but the button is invisible. It works to press it, because it prints out "Button pressed", but i cant see the button.

Comment: Can you post all of your code in that class including the declaration of the function and class?

Comment: I added the code in Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/53hkjCXJ and http://pastebin.com/Wq79ct2e . Also I am using the class "LikeShape.swift" for the UIButton class, but still no shape showing.

Comment: I looked at your code, and there is something wrong with the code in your bezierPath. Try replacing the code with this shape- `bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(70, 1))
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(139.28, 41))
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(139.28, 121))
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(70, 161))
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(0.72, 121))
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(0.72, 41))`

Comment: Still not working tho.. This is my button: http://s9.postimg.org/5pt3ba93z/Screen_Shot_2016_04_12_at_14_48_41.png

Comment: Are you sure that your shape that you made in PaintCode is closed? Double check. This is a mistake you made while creating the shape in PaintCode. Because I created a hexagon in PaintCode and tested it, and it worked just fine.

Comment: Can you make a shape and send me the full code for the shape so i can test it out? - And yes i think i closed it, because i also used fill color white.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108938/discussion-between-krish-wadhwana-and-roduck-nickes).

Answer (score 0):

You can add path in layer. (here `shapeLayer` declared as property.)

```
if (self.shapeLayer != nil) {
    [self.shapeLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    self.shapeLayer = nil;
}
_shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
self.shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0;
self.shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
self.shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
self.shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor;
[[self.button layer] addSublayer:self.shapeLayer];
```